# python os.open usage while opening a directory

Tags: python

I have this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 8 abc root 4096 Dec 21 19:56 javaprac
```

This works:

```
>>> fd = os.open(os.getcwd() , os.O_RDONLY)
```

But why do these two fail:

```
>>> fd = os.open(os.getcwd() , os.O_RDWR)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/abc/javaprac'

>>> fd = os.open(os.getcwd() , os.O_WRONLY)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/abc/javaprac'
```

Comment: Why do you want to write *directly* to the directory node? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters My question is simple and direct with no deeper  meaning: Why can't I write to a directory like this ? Why is the behavior the way it is?

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, at least, you cannot write to a directory.

```
$ echo hello >> .
bash: .: Is a directory
```

You can read from a directory, that what the *ls* and *dir* commands do.